# HTML5 Session Storage for list

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

How would I define sessionStorage for a dropdown list? I have the following, but I get "someTitle is not defined"

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**Javascript**

```
function save_page(form) {
    if (supports_html5_storage()) {
        var title = $('.btn-group-month ul li > a').attr('title');
        sessionStorage.setItem("someTitle", title);
    }
}

function load_page(form) {
    if (supports_html5_storage()) {
        var title = sessionStorage.getItem("someTitle");
        $('.btn-group-month ul li > a').attr('title', title);
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-month">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span data-bind="label">Month</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-month">
    <li><a href="#" title="January">January</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="February">February</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="March">March</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12229/)

Comment: I copy-pasted the code in my local server and it seems not to throwing any errors. But it doesn't seems to be doing anything useful - save_page always saves January and load_page corrupts all the months to have title="January". Can you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: Sure, thanks for responding. I'm trying to save the selected item to sessionStorage so that it can persist to a new page. So if a user selects February, that is saved in storage, and passed onto a new page. Apparently something is wrong with my code in both places but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Ok, looking at the HTML, this looks like Bootstrap - is it? I looked at the documentation of Bootstrap and I cannot find a component that looks like a dropdown menu and actually changes the value when clicked. How are you visually doing the change, so I know what to look for. Right now, with the supplied HTML there is no selected item or anything - I don't know what item to look for when saving and when loading - where and how to show the selected item. Can you supply just the HTML for when something is selected?

Comment: What is the use of form parameter in the functions? Also, $('.btn-group-month ul li > a').attr('title') will take your first anchor's title and not the one selected. You should rather call the functions onchange so that you can get the values of that month

Comment: @metal03326 Yes, I'm using Bootstrap. I'm going to add a jsfiddle in just a sec with the Bootstrap stuff and some more JS. Thank you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/qor0qesh/ i have done the same with basic drop down list , hope it helps you !

Comment: @KishoreSahas This doesn't apply to my question as I'm using a ul li rather than a select. Thank you, though!

Comment: I hope i will be able to help you if you are able to provide a jsfiddle !

Answer (score 1):

In the code, you are reading the incorrect data. This:

```
var title = $('.btn-group-month ul li > a').attr('title');
```

will read the `title` attribute for the first link in the list. But that's not the value that you want. That value will always be "January" and it will corrupt the values of the rest of the list (as specified by [metal03326](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644683/html5-session-storage-for-list#comment53137306_32644683) in the comments).

What you want to read (and set) is the value of the first `span` in the button, as that is the selected value. To do that, you need to change the selector a little:

```
var title = $('.btn-group-month button > span:first()').text();
```

That will read the selected value correctly. Now to set it again when the new page loads, you need to modify that `span` too:

```
var title = sessionStorage.getItem("someTitle");
if (title) {
    $('.btn-group-month button > span:first()').text(title);
}
```

---

You can see the whole code here, but it won't work as it doesn't support sessionStorage while on sandbox mode. So [you can see it working on this JSFiddle too](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12245/).

```js
function supports_html5_storage() {
  try {
    return 'sessionStorage' in window && window['sessionStorage'] !== null;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

function save_page(form) {
  if (supports_html5_storage()) {

    var storage = window.sessionStorage;

    // AM - new selector
    var title = $('.btn-group-month button > span:first()').text();
    sessionStorage.setItem("someTitle", title);

    form.filter(':input').each(function(ind,elem) {
      if (elem.name && elem.value) {
        storage.setItem(elem.name,elem.value);
      }
      else {
        //storage.someTitle=$('ul.dropdown-menu-month li').find('a').attr('title');
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("HTML5 storage not available");
  }
}

function load_page(form)
{
  if (supports_html5_storage()) {

    var title = sessionStorage.getItem("someTitle");
    // AM - new selector
    if (title) {
      $('.btn-group-month button > span:first()').text(title);
    }

    var storage = window.sessionStorage;

    form.filter(':input').each(function(ind,elem) {
      if (elem.name) {
        $('.edit-image-container img.img-verify').attr('src',storage.galleryImg);
        elem.value = storage.getItem(elem.name);
      } else {
        //
      }
    });
  }
}


// Enable dropdown to display chosen value
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(){
  var elementVal = $(this).text();

  $(this).closest('.input-append').find('#appendedInputButton').val(elementVal);
});


// Dropdown picker
$('.dropdown-menu').on( 'click', 'li', function( event ) {
  var $target = $( event.currentTarget );
  $target.closest( '.btn-group' )
  .find( '[data-bind="label"]' ).text( $target.text() )
  .end()
  .children( '.dropdown-toggle' ).dropdown( 'toggle' );

  // AM - Save form
  save_page($("form"));

  return false;
});

// AM - Load form
load_page($("form"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-month">
    <button type="button" name="dropdownval" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span data-bind="label">Month</span><span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-month" name="month">
      <li><a href="#" title="January">January</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="February">February</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="March">March</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```